# Are there any apps for route planning/following?

Tags: apps, location-services

I'm looking for an app for route planning. I want to follow a predefined route (it's a strava segment, but it's very long) because I don't know the route and think I'll get lost without guidance.

Does anyone know of an app where I can load up a route (through GPX maybe?) and follow it along on my phone?

Comment: Specifically for Strava, there are a few dedicated apps that connect to them directly like [Brava](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=d74c6fb9-2886-43ab-873e-863f37d33fda) (Although I can't vouch for how good it is, as I don't use Strava)

Comment: @RowlandShaw you should post this as answer. Looks good.

Comment: Brava is good for route tracking, not route planning

Comment: Your question did specifically say "I want to follow a predefined route (it's a strava segment"...

Comment: @RowlandShaw yes, but there's a difference between "tracking" a ride (ie: having my phone follow where I am and then after the fact, show me a track of where I rode) and "following a predifined route" (ie: Loading the route up before my ride and then getting instructions on which roads to follow during the ride to make sure I follow the route I want to without getting lost). Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've done some research and have come up with this:

- Use [BikeMap.net](http://www.bikemap.net/) to draw the route and save a GPX
- Upload the gpx file to OneDrive
- Use [GPX Viewer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-au/store/app/gpx-viewer/e34b097a-d751-4aab-b20c-ece6b6ae0eed?signin=true) to download and view the route

I haven't tried it in the wild yet, so I'm not sure how good it will be for tracking the route. Still, seems promising!